# Android MultiThreading is working in Android 8.0 but not Android 11

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-theme

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        String[] themeStrings = {"Light","Dark","System Default"};
        ListView lv = requireView().findViewById(R.id.themeChangeLV);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,themeStrings);
        lv.setAdapter(ad);
        

        sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("MODE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        nightMODE = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("night",false);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                                editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.night),false);
                                editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.sdt),false);
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                        }).start();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                                editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.night),true);
                                editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.sdt),false);
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                        }).start();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.sdt),true);
                        editor.apply();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The code above me uses a new thread to change **APP THEME** so that my app doesn't go BLACK for around half a second.

And it works in an emulator (Android 8.0), but in my phone (Android 11), what happens is on click, the app stops working?

Can anyone help me this?

Comment: Can you share the error stack trace?

Answer (score -2):

It also depends upon the mobile setting in developers option you should change them.

Comment: how ? There are so many options ? Can u specify which one plz?

Comment: Give screenshots / names or path for the options

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).